# How to access a many-to-many join model attribute for a not persisted record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Given the following structure where a `Step` has many `Items` and an `Item` has many nested `Items`:

```
class Step
  has_many :step_items
  has_many :items, through: :step_items
end

class Item
  has_one :step_item
  has_one :step, through: :step_item

  has_many :nested_items, foreign_key: :parent_item_id
  has_many :items, through: :nested_items
end

class StepItem
  belongs_to :step
  belongs_to :item
end

class NestedItem
  belongs_to :parent_item, foreign_key: :parent_item_id
  belongs_to :item
end
```

How could I access the join model when "building" nested `Items`?

For example, for an `Item` that was related to a `Step` I could retrieve the `StepItem` like this:

```
step.items.build.step_item # => StepItem
```

How would I access the specific instance of the `NestedItem` model when building items:

```
item = step.items.build.items.build # => Item
item.??? # How do I retrieve the `NestedItem` that joins `item` to it's parent?
```

Answer (score 1):

Your terminology is a little off, so I'm not quite sure what you're asking:

```
For example, for an Item that was related to a Step I could retrieve the StepItem like this:

step.items.build.step_item # => StepItem
```

That's not retrieving an item, that's building a new one.  But I *think* what you want is

```
parent_item = step.items.build
item = parent_item.items.build # => Item
parent_item.nested_items.find{|ne| ne.item == item}
```

But you may really want a relationship from Item to parent_item[s].

The real question may be why you want to get at the nested_item at all since it has done its whole job already.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm looking to access the instance of the join model (NestedItem) because it has additional attributes I want to set while building the Item. Your idea to iterate through `parent.nested_items` is the only thing that I've found that works but it seems a little clunky to say the least. I was wondering if there is a direct way to access the join model from an instance of Item.

Comment: If there are attributes on the join table then it should not just be a join model :-)

You probably also want to investigate `accepts_nested_attributes_for`